# Can not receive some mails sent by SMS Backup+ Android app when using Gmail mail delegate feature

Tags: backup, gmail

I currently backup my Android phone data using SMS Backup+. Data entries are written to Gmail: e.g. each phone call is logged as one message labeled with the `call log` tag and automatically archived.

I want to share those entries with another Gmail account so that I use the mail delegate (e.g. "Grant access to your account") Gmail feature, but I cannot see the SMS Backup+ mails in this delegated account.

I can see other auto-archived mails normally, such as Facebook notification messages.

My question is: How can I view the SMS Backup+ log messages in my delegated Gmail account?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid the question is a bit unclear (to me at least). Once you grant access to your account, that other account will be able to access ALL your email, but they won't show up in the other account's inbox, instead you will have to "switch" accounts in gmail. Something like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/88791830/Selection_001.png.

Comment: We read the delegate mail directly in our own inbox after granting access Hamzeh